# Transition between 4 html sites

Tags: html, css, animation, transactions

I'm making a website for myself and I want to make transitions between my subsites like PowerPoint slide transitions. I've already found a codepen that fits (https://codepen.io/mburakerman/pen/roJmaZ) but the problem is I have no idea of pug and stylus. Also, visual studio code tells me that the stylus code has an error. I'm also new to programming so I'm not really able to figure out how to use that right.
Main site if you need the code for the other sides too let me know.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
a:link {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
    h1 {
        z-index: 2;
    font-size: 250%;
}

body {
    z-index: 2;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1.5;
    background: #03FFEA;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 300%;
    z-index: 2;
    color: white;
}

.Work { 
    font-size: 150%;
    flex-direction: row;
    display: flex;
    align-self: center;
    align-content: center;
    z-index: 3;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-5vh);
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.About {
    font-size: 150%;
    flex-direction: row;
    display: flex;
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(4vw);
    z-index: 3;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 45vh;
    text-align: center;
}

.Contact {
    font-size: 150%;
    flex-direction: row;
    display: flex;
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(6vw);
    z-index: 3;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 45vh;
    text-align: center;
}

* { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
*:before, *:after { -webkit-box-sizing: inherit; -moz-box-sizing: inherit; box-sizing: inherit; }
body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#video-viewport { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; z-index: -1; }
video { display: block; width: 100%; height: auto; }

.fullsize-video-bg { height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }

.fullsize-video-bg .inner { display: table; width: 100%; max-width: 24em; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; position: relative; z-index: 2; text-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5); }
.fullsize-video-bg .inner > div { text-align: center; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; padding: 0 2em; }


h1 { font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif; font-size: 3em; line-height: .9; font-weight: 900; letter-spacing: -.025em; text-transform: uppercase; margin-bottom: .5em; }
h1 + p { font-family: "Shadows Into Light Two", cursive; font-size: 1.5em;  }

@media (min-aspect-ratio:16/9){
    .videoBG {
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Main.css">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Main.js"></script>
<title>Document</title>
    </head>
    
<body>
    <main>
    <!--Links-->
    <div class="About">
        <a href="About.html">
            <h1>
                ABOUT
            </h1>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="Work">
        <a href="Work.html">
            <h1>
                WORK
            </h1>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="Contact">
        <a href="Contact.html">
            <h1>
                CONTACT
            </h1>
        </a>
    </div>

        <!--Videohintergrund-->
    <section class="fullsize-video-bg">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
    <div id="video-viewport">
        <video width="1920" height="1080" autoplay muted loop>
            <source src="BG_Video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
    </div>
</section>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for all that help.